# Click a listbox item open WebBrowser

Tags: c#

In a webbrowser control I have a listbox. Data on the html page has loaded up listbox, how can I click on each item in the listbox and open an html page that corresponds? (html pages that have been put in the debug folder of the project). Can I use the SelectedIndexChanged event or not?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: I didn't down vote you but please do research before asking another question on [SO]. Read the [FAQ]'s.. and Google [ask]

Answer (score 0):

In the SelectedIndexChanged event, get the newly selected value of the listbox and open the URL...

```
System.Diagnostic.Process.Start(urlFromListBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you and if you use a webbrowser control then please try something like this

```
private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var myUri = new Uri("/" + Uri.EscapeDataString((string)listBox.SelectedItem), UriKind.Relative);

    NavigationService.Navigate(myUri);
}
```